# Is there a way to use the formatted output from a cell, rather than the unformatted value?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Is there a way to generically grab the text output of a numeric formatted cell? For example:

(A) I have a cell formatted as Percent - the cell may well show "20%" while containing the value 0.2
(B) I have another cell formatted as Currency, showing "$20,000" where the actual value is 20000

I want to be able to extract (generically) the text result of these cells without knowing ahead of time what the format in use is in the particular cell. So imagine a function

=CellText(A1)

- If I point it at (A) I would get "20%" as the result
- if I point it at (B) I would get "$20,000" as the result

Is there anything already like this in Excel? Ideally I'd like to accomplish it without VBA ...

Thanks, Ken

Comment: Since number formatting is just a way of representing a numeric value I cannot think of a convenient way in which you would avoid VBA and the `Range.Text` property. If there are only a few formats you are interested in you could think of [`CELL`](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-cell-function), though being little dynamic and volatile you could use: `=TEXT(A1,INDEX({"0%","[$$-en-US]#.##0"},MATCH(CELL("format",A1),{"P0",".0"},0)))` and extend to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, to get the formatted content of some cell use

```
SomeCell.Text
```

where `SomeCell` is a range object set to a single cell.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see, you would need VBA as stated. For example:

```
Sub TestFormat()
    MsgBox GetCellFormatValue(ActiveCell)
End Sub

Function GetCellFormatValue(r As Range) As Variant
    If r.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
    On Error Resume Next
    GetCellFormatValue = Format(r.Value, r.NumberFormat)
End Function
```